# CQ5:: search results not coming up

Tags: search, aem

I have been trying to fetch a user using Map and these are the search criterion:

```
path= /home/users
type=rep:User
property=@jcr:content/rep:fullname
property.value= some existing user
```

This works well in query debugger (replacing @jcr:content/rep:fullname with rep:fullname) but in the code it doesn't fetch any search result. I have tried rep:fullname, @jcr:content/rep:fullname and some other ideas but no success yet. Any pointers ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello there, what do you mean by using Map, are you using the Sling's ResourceResolver within a servlet or are you using a Templating Tag could you please post the way you are using this "Map" Class or object

Comment: If this is working in QueryBuilder then it should work in the code too, unless there are any access resitrictions for the user to view the home directory. Can you post the part of the code where you are setting values to your map object?